# Building FLTK Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opengl, build-process, linker-errors, fltk

I am having trouble getting set up with FLTK in Eclipse.  I am trying to create an OpenGL window with the following code (which I found [here](http://www.gidforums.com/t-10971.html)):

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H>
#include <FL/gl.h>

//
// Simple resizable 2D GL  window
// erco 10/08/05
//
class MyGlWindow : public Fl_Gl_Window {
    // DRAW METHOD
    //       OpenGL window: (w,h) is upper right, (-w,-h) is lower left, (0,0) is center
    //
    void draw() {
        // First time? init viewport, etc.
        if (!valid()) {
            valid(1);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glViewport(0,0,w(),h());
            glOrtho(-w(),w(),-h(),h(),-1,1);
        }
        //  Clear screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //  Draw white 'X'
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); glVertex2f(w(), h()); glVertex2f(-w(),-h()); glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); glVertex2f(w(),-h()); glVertex2f(-w(), h()); glEnd();
    }
    // HANDLE WINDOW RESIZING
    //    If window reshaped, need to readjust viewport/ortho
    //
    void resize(int X,int Y,int W,int H) {
        Fl_Gl_Window::resize(X,Y,W,H);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glViewport(0,0,W,H);
        glOrtho(-W,W,-H,H,-1,1);
        redraw();
    }
public:
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    MyGlWindow(int X,int Y,int W,int H,const char*L=0) : Fl_Gl_Window(X,Y,W,H,L) {
    }
};
// MAIN
int main() {
     Fl_Window win( 500,  300);
     MyGlWindow mygl(10, 10, win.w()-20, win.h()-20);
     win.resizable(mygl);
     win.show();
     return(Fl::run());
}
```

Here are the commands being issued:

```
make -k all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/FL -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: Experiment01
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib -o"Experiment01"  ./main.o   -lGL -lfltk
```

And here are the errors:

```
/usr/include/FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::init()'
/usr/include/FL/Fl_Gl_Window.H undefined reference to `vtable for Fl_Gl_Window'
undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::~Fl_Gl_Window()'
undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::resize(int, int, int, int)'
```

What else do I need to link?  I've tried -llibfltk.so -llibfltk_gl.so, etc., but it always says that it cannot find the specified library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the [chapter "Basic Example"](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/example1.html)?

> You will probably need to tell the compiler where to find the directory "fltk" with all the header files. This is usually done using the -I option added to the compiler line:

```
c++ -I/usr/local/include ...
```

> Similarly, when linking your application you will need to tell the compiler to use the FLTK library and where to find it. In X you need to include several libraries that fltk calls:

```
c++ ... -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk2 -lXext -lXinerama -lXft -lX11 -lXi -lm
```

In your case, may be not all the header definitions of FL are in `/usr/include/FL`: there may be some elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, unfortunately FLTK 1.x does not provide (at least the last time I checked it did not) the excellent `fltk2-config` script from the FLTK2 branch, which you can invoke like:

```
fltk2-config --use-gl --ldflags
```

And the output may be:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -lfltk2_gl -lGLU -lGL -lfltk2 -lX11 -lXi -lXinerama -lXft -ldl -lpthread -lm -lXext
```

So, I believe the LDFLAGS for a FLTK 1.x application would be:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -lfltk_gl -lGLU -lGL -lfltk -lX11 -lXi -lXinerama -lXft -ldl -lpthread -lm -lXext
```